# I want to fix a button position in the scroll view in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3

[image]

I want to fix a button position in the scroll view, but scroll view has scrollable content also this button has outer from scroll view frame. I researched a lot but can't find the solution.
Scroll view has Blue color and the main view has the green color, the main view is the parent of the scroll view. And button has a yellow color, I want this button in scroll view but not scrollable, and its position will be same as the image.

Comment: Then you should add the Button outside of UIScrollview and button's bottom position should be set to ViewController's view bottom to be on same place. You shouldn't set button's bottom to scroll view bottom.

Comment: @Bharath You are right. But When I click on that button, then this should appear in scroll view and not it can scroll.

Comment: By the term "this" do you mean the button should come inside scroll view ?

Comment: Yes, when I click on the button this should come inside the scroll view.

Comment: Okay, should it scroll after coming inside scroll view ?

Comment: Yes, It scroll after coming inside scroll view.

Comment: Good thank you, then I would suggest to set the button's constraint through code and not the Storyboard. Please check how to set constraints via code and try it out, because in storyboard this seams not possible.

Comment: Okay thanks for help :)

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem. Simply set a scroll view delegate and add a `DidScroll` method for the scroll view.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    //SET BUTTON POSSITION WHERE YOU WANT IT WILL NOT SCROLL 
    button.frame.origin.y = (scrollView.contentOffset.y + self.view.frame.size.height - 50)
}
```